# Is there a WORKING qrCode reader in Js/Jquery out there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, there are just a few Js plugins to read a barcode in browser windows from a smartphone.

I have tried:
https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/
http://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/
https://dwa012.github.io/html5-qrcode/
https://webqr.com/

I got the camera work for QuaggaJs, but i cannot run the scanner.
So is there anyone using a working Barcode reader plugin, who can point me in the right direction?

I need to read the code live with my phone, in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To other peoples searching for something like this.
I found this: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-From-Web-Pages

You need to have a app installed, and invoke it from your website.
I guess it will be the closest i´ll come...

Comment: can you make a chat room I would like to ask some thing.

Comment: I don't know how to make a chat room?

Comment: [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125314/discussion-between-trafalgar-d-law-and-wiktor-stribizew) try to enter

Comment: can you enter in the room?

Comment: okay2 thanks Im also online now.

Comment: Mate are you still there?

Comment: Yes, i have answered...

Comment: can you teach me how to do it?. Like what you said in chat?

Comment: It's very simple, if you just follow the link in my answer..